# display specific sections of log files on linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, logging

I'm searching for a way to get specific informations out of a log file.

This is my log file :

```
------
[SQL STATEMENT
MAYBE
SEVERAL
LINES
LONG
]
ERR: [01.02.2012 14:17:44] [[SOME][MORE][INFO] additional debug informations]
[corresponding source file]
------
[SQL STATEMENT
MAYBE
SEVERAL
LINES
LONG
]
ERR: [01.02.2012 14:21:42] [[SOME][MORE][INFO] additional debug informations]
 [corresponding source file]
------
[SQL STATEMENT
MAYBE
SEVERAL
LINES
LONG
]
DEBUG: [23.08.2011 22:30:01] []
 [corresponding source file]
------
```

This log file contais debug and error information of sql statements.
What I need is to get all blocks of sql error messages out of this log file.

These blocks are seperated by lines with '------'.

Like the first entry of the file the error messages are represented by an 'ERR:' in the
message block.
How can I get these messages out of the file.
I didn't want to write special scripts for that kind of task.
So it would be nice if this can be done by using command line tools.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well you should show your efforts. We are here to help, but not for finishing your tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` can do it for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="------" ; ORS=RS}
     $0 ~ "ERR: " { print }' INPUTFILE
```

Will print the `ERR:` blocks. If you want the others just replace `~` to `!~`.

[See it in action here](http://ideone.com/3i9sU).

Comment: Hey thank you. This is pretty impressive. And I agree with you, but I would have needed several lines of code for this and I was wondering if it doable with just one short command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep:

```
grep ERR: filename
```

Comment: Sorry grep on its own would just print the lines in which the ERR: pattern appears.